# Google Play Story Hi Res Icon

Tags: android, image

I'm trying to upload my app to Google Play story but it says my Hi Res Icon is invalid. I've triple checked that it's 512x512, 32bit etc. The only thing I can think of is it isn't alpha?

Any help would be fantastic, thanks!

My Icon:

[image: My Icon]

My Error:
[image: My Error]

Comment: Download [paint.net](http://www.getpaint.net/download.html) or [do it online](https://resizeappicon.com/).

Answer (score 2):

As described on Google Play Store developer console, icon image should be:
512 x 512, 32-bit PNG (with alpha)

Try to change that and solved.

Re-saving with [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/download.html)  (Solution by `@activesince93` )

Answer (score 0):

It could be the file size? The maximum size allowed is 1024kb.